# How to auto populate a date based on checkbox action Mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently doing a project in .net MVC4 and I have requirement to populate a Display field with current date, when a checkbox is ticked in the Edit form.

Since it's an edit form Checkbox, might be ticked already and I need to check if it's selected the first time then I need to populate the current date.

---

Update:

Matt Thanks..I got this around by using Hidden field. 
Steps involved: 
1. store the model field in Hidden field in your Edit Screen.
        @Html.Hidden("hiddenDateField", Model.DateField)
        @Html.Hidden("hiddenCheckBox", Model.CheckBoxField)

1. Then using JQuery I added following logic..

$('#chkBox').on('click', function () {
        var myDate = new Date();
        var displayDate = (myDate.getUTCDate()) + '/' +(myDate.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' + myDate.getUTCFullYear() + " " + myDate.getUTCHours() +":" + myDate.getUTCMinutes() +":"+myDate.getUTCSeconds();

```
    if ($('#chkBox').is(":checked")) {
        if ($('#hiddenCheckBox').val() == "False") {       // This condition is to check if the user is selecting checkbox for 1st time by comparing with received model data value.
            $('#lblDate').text(displayDate);
        } else {
            $('#lblDate').text($('#hiddenDateField').val());  // This condition is to restore the Date if user unticks  and Select Checkbox again.
        }
    }
    if (!$('#chkBox').is(":checked")) {  // This when user unticks the checkbox and I replaced the date to empty char.
          $('#lblDate').text("");

    }
});
```

Comment: I can try using jquery and ajax but want to know if we have alternate option using HTML helper.. moreover I am new to .net MVC..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to use ajax,  just use jquery.  without your code it is hard to give an example so you will need to change this to match your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //this will check if checked on load and set the text box to now
    if($('.chkClass').is(":checked")){
        $('.txtClass').val($.now());
    }
    $('.chkClass').on('click', function(){
        //check again so it only sets the date if they check and not uncheck
        if($('.chkClass').is(":checked")){
            $('.txtClass').val($.now());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Matt Thanks..I got this around by using Hidden field. Steps involed

Comment: glad you got it working.  if my answer helped would you mind marking it as the answer?